# Project name different from artifact-Id

Tags: eclipse, maven, m2e

When I import Maven projects from my workspace and these projects are children of a parent project, they're imported with project name exactly like the artifact-id. But when I import a parent project, the project name is just like the directory name.

Example of directory structure:

```
project-parent (artifactId = project-application-parent)
--web (artifactId = project-webapp)
--core (artifactId = project-core)
```

When I import all projects my workspace looks like this:

```
project-parent
project-webapp
project-core
```

What I want is to parent project be named like his artifact-id (project-application-parent). Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: Can you rename the parent project? Importing is a one-off process, after all...

Comment: @vikingsteve do you mean rename the project folder? Yes, I can. But it doesn't solve my question.

Comment: Well, dare I say that if this is a "once per project import" operation then it shouldnt be such a hassle? unless of course you are importing projects over and over.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is possible setting the `projectNameTemplate` property in the `configuration` of the `maven-eclipse-plugin`, as in [Documentation](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-eclipse-plugin/eclipse-mojo.html#projectNameTemplate).

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>x.y</version>
  <configuration>
    <projectNameTemplate>custom-project-name</projectNameTemplate>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 2):

One way to rename the project is directly editing the `.project` file. This is a XML file located in the project folder with basic eclipse information about the project.

Just change the node  (it will only affect the project name in Eclipse)

Comment: I am wondering now, is there a way to run eclipse in non-interactive mode, to tell it to import the project, and then run a sed-style command to edit the `.project` file, and do all of this in one script?

Comment: I really don't, but another way is creating the eclipse files with the maven command "mvn eclipse:eclipse". The option 'projectNameTemplate' lets you to set a personalized name for the project. More info http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-eclipse-plugin/eclipse-mojo.html

Answer (score 2):

The problem occurs if the project is located in the workspace. If you move the project out of the workspace, the problem no longer occurs.

Comment: This really feels like a bug in m2e. How did you discover that this is the answer?